# Removing Yellow Bleach stain from laminate counter

Tags: cleaning, laminate

I had a blue stain on my white laminate vanity.
picked up some bleach based bathroom cleaning liquid, for a few things.

Thought I would give it a try on the stain on the counter.
I left it for a few hours.
It took the blue stain right off.
However left a much larger yellow one.

Obviously I won't make that mistake again.
However now I am left with the problem of the yellow stain.

So far I have been removing it with repeated application of vinegar and baking soda.
It is working, but very slowly (as in I expect to be doing this for many days).

I have read that [Silver Jewlery Cleaner work](http://ths.gardenweb.com/forums/load/disaster/msg0511201213077.html?18)s to solve it, does anyone have any experience with using this?

My other option I have been considering is wet-and-dry sand paper.
I have some very fine stuff, but even so I'm not to happy with the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It took the blue stain right off. However left a *much larger* yellow one.

So the bleach yellowed the counter. Bleach is an oxidixer, so you'll need a reducing agent to reverse its effect. [Dithionite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_dithionite) is a good choice, and is sold in stores as ["Iron out" or "Super Iron Out"](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=sb&q=%22Iron%20out%22%20%20%22Super%20Iron%20Out%22&oq=%22Iron%20out%22%20%20%22Super%20Iron%20Out%22&gs_l=serp.12..0i7i30j0i30.6120.8213.0.10082.2.2.0.0.0.0.262.435.0j1j1.2.0....0...1c.1.38.serp..0.2.433.KsSbwXwHEao). Lacking that, anything that smells vaguely like sulfur, or ammonia-like even is worth a try. Ordinary surfactant based cleaning agents aren't likely to help you here.

Comment: So thus silver polish makes sense.

Comment: @Oxinabox Maybe. Trouble is you can clean sulfides (tarnish) off silver either by reducing them back to Ag (as in the Al foil/NaHCo3 method) or by dissolving the sulfides, plus some Ag, with an acid that forms soluble silver salts I've used HNO3, less nasty acids and salts work too. The reduction method may work for you (Al + NaHCO3), but the acid method doesn't depend on redox chemistry so may not work. Unless you can look at the ingredients in your silver polish and say "Oh, that's got a reducing agent in it, you're better off going with a product you know works by reduction, the "Iron out".

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I'll head to the hardware store on the way home.

Comment: Actually couldn't buy rust converter at the hardware store. They only had a phosphoric acid based rust remover.
So I got some ammonia based silver cleaner. A reducing agent as you suggest.
Definite improvements, though it is still there.
I think perhaps a few more applications/giving more time

Answer (score 1):

I used Barkeeper's Friend (a cleaning powder). You just apply it to the stain, get it wet, and rub with a towel until the stain lifts. You have to keep it at but it does work!